# Diskette animation booting IBM x3550 7978CBG

Tags: ibm, ibm-xseries

I have to manage / reinstall an ibm x3550 model 7978CBG server but it can't boot from cd.

I have put in the cd some bootable cd's such Centos 6 ( some flavors ) and Proxmox ve but the server does not boot.

I thought could be configuration / boot order issue, so I changed it in BIOS booting first from cd but until now there is no luck.

The system boots and shows an animation drawing a drive and a diskette suggesting you press F1 key.

I am not sure, but I believe I have no wrong disk configuration.

The system bios version is 1.09

I am searching redbooks, advice or a hand.

Thanks

**CLOSED: drive detected as primary master, but it was broken**

thanks to all.

Comment: Which x3550? The original? What's the Machine Type?

Comment: @MikeyB IBM x3550  type 7978.

Comment: Are you sure the CD drive isn't broken or just dirty ? I know from experience they hardly ever get used on a server, until you need to re-install. If you got a can of compressed air try to blow any accumulated dust from the lens of the laser. That is often all it takes to get a long-time unused CD drive working again.

Comment: @Tonny I think it's not broken, drive is displayed on boot and diagnostics test passed under diags menu.

Comment: This is not IBM-midrange, which refers to the lineage of the AS/400 family of systems.

Comment: @ppk Unless the diags really attempt to read a disk in the drive passed diags doesn't mean anything. The only way to check for a dirty lens is by actually reading a disk..

Comment: @Tonny the drive was clean, but it was broken. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You BIOS version (and probably other firmware versions) are outdated. Current BIOS version is 1.17. Update might fix your issues.

Best method to update / install your server is to use UpdateXpress from IBM which is network booted.

You can temporarily select boot method by pressing F12 on IBM System x servers.

URL to get updates from: http://www.ibm.com/support (FixCentral)

Comment: Might be outdated, but so outdated that it can't boot from cd ? Going to update and check. Thanks